# Need architecture idea for POS

Tags: mobile, architecture

Me and my team will be developing a POS system for a restaurant chain.

In addition to a windows application for the POS, the main idea is to make a native (not HTML5) mobile application that will help in tracking orders.

The mobile app should do this - 
 
1. Waiters will take and track order.
 
2. The manager should be able to check employees's leaves,timings,etc.

On the POS part - 
 
We are thinking to make a particular restaurant work with its local database that will get synced with the central database.

Are we on the right track?
Can HTML5 help us in the mobile application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many do you willing to pay for me to give you the architecture? Just kidding.

Think of a retailer that:

- Has only 10 kind of items
- With sell only 5 quantity of each items each day
- That has only 1 staff and it is his/her family
- That sell only with cash and not electronic payments

Do you think that kind of retailer need a mobile application which can do POS with cloud computing support? Of course not. He/she maybe only need a book written manually with simple accounting debit credit to track his/her income/expense. But a big company like W*lmart will do.

If you want to make an application, make sure that you has the requirement. Why bother create something that is not needed?

If you want to make a general POS application, collect the basic requirement first. What they need. Will they do input by entering the item code, or scanning using barcode? Will they need to make a payment after the item being entered (typical retailer system), or they need to make a payment after they asked for the bill (typical restaurant system). It will later decide your architecture.

Now asking your question:

> > In addition to a windows application for the POS, the main idea is to make a native (not HTML5) mobile application that will help in tracking orders

As I have have said before, the architecture will depend on the device used and how the process be done.

> > The mobile app should do this -
> >
> > 1. Waiters will take and track order.
> > 2. The manager should be able to check employees's leaves,timings,etc.

First point is your requirement but 2nd point. What? Track employee's leaves, timings,etc? It should be included in `HR` module, not POS module. Keep your application scope to the smallest and make sure that each of your module are in same topic.

> > On the POS part - 
> >     We are thinking to make a particular restaurant work with its local database that will get synced with the central database.

Try it and you will know whether this distributed database design are good or not. Search for articles about pros and cons for this design and make sure you know the sequences before starting design.

> > Are we on the right track? Can HTML5 help us in the mobile application?

It is like a same question as: Can a keyboard help us type? HTML5 is a language used in any web - server programming. It is kind alike of rendering / layout technique. If you want to aim for modern browser such as latest version of firefox, then go for it. But really, do you know how HTML5 can help you, or do you know what are the downside of using HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

- Since this app will only be used by employees of the restaurant,
  (not by customers), it would be safe to assume targeted mobile
  platform, Android or IOS.
- Since, the inventory, employees leaves    etc is being tracked in
  restaurant locally, the idea of using local    DB which syncs with
  the remote DB seems the right approach.
- The    menu of items and their codes should stored at central DB
  server and    fetched from there.

---